# set or unordered_set of a vector of unordered_set 's of integers

Tags: c++, boost, hash

I am having trouble declaring a variable which I intend to use as either an `unordered_set` or a `set` of `vector`s whose elements are themselves `unordered_set<int>`s. My application generates a large number of `vector<unordered_set<int>`'s that could repeat and hence the decision to go with `set` or `unordered_set` of these `vector`s so that only the unique ones are stored for later processing.

```
std::unordered_set<std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>, \
boost::hash<std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>>> Variable1;
```

gives error `boost::hash_value - none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types`. Is there a boost/nonboost way of providing the appropriate hash function?

Usage of a `set` like so:

```
std::set<std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>> Variable2;
```

requires specification of of `<` operator to compare two different `vector`s of `unordered_set`s

Are there pre-defined ways to implement the `<` operator for `vector`s of `unordered_set`s ?

Comment: What would you expect the hash of a vector to be? Is it the hash of all its elements? That could be quite expensive to compute - and might change all the time. What else could it be? The vector does not consist of much: a pointer to begin, a pointer to end and a pointer to capacity. And those could change when the vector needs to reallocate. So what's left is just the address of the vector.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I was hoping that the hash of [{1,2,3},{4,5,6}] where the inner sets are unordered sets is different from [{4,5,6},{1,2,3}] at the very least -- i.e., the hash preserves the ordering within the vector. Perhaps computing this hash would be expensive - I am not sure/aware. The only other brute force way I am aware of is to individually compare the vector of unordered sets explicitly by looping over the elements of the vector and comparing the unordered sets. I was hoping for something more efficient than this, but it may be my only resort.

Comment: Let's wait if someone comes up with a good solution. I can't help much. Sorry.

Comment: `std::vector` *does* have `operator<`, so maybe `std::set<std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>>` might be more suitable here.

Comment: @PaulSanders You are right...https://godbolt.org/z/nadPd177h seems to compile. On my compiler, it seems to provide errors in xutility, xmemory and xstddef. Let me delve into this. Thanks for your comment. It helped!

Comment: The linked code compiles for me with Visual Studio 2022. I assume that's what you're using since xmemory is a familiar header. If you tell us what compiler/version you're using and show us the code and errors perhaps we can help.

Comment: @RetiredNinja On a standalone project I created now with nothing else in it, the code compiles fine on my compiler too. However, in the presence of the rest of the code of my application, I get the errors I mentioned. So, let me delve into it further and try to see if I can come up with a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to create a container that stores either an unordered_set or a set of vectors whose elements are themselves unordered_sets. I think you're encountering issues with hashing and comparison operators. Let's address these:

**1. Hash Function for `std::unordered_set` of `std::vector` of `std::unordered_set<int>s`:**
To use `std::unordered_set` of `std::vector` of `std::unordered_set<int>s`, you need to provide a hash function. Here's a way to define a custom hash function using Boost:

```
    #include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
    #include <unordered_set>
    #include <vector>

    namespace std {
        template <>
        struct hash<std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>> {
            size_t operator()(const std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>& v) const {
                size_t seed = 0;
                for (const auto& uset : v) {
                    boost::hash_combine(seed, uset);
                }
                return seed;
            }
        };
    }
```

This hash function iterates through the vector of unordered sets and combines the hash values using `boost::hash_combine`

**2. Comparison Operator for `std::set` of `std::vector` of `std::unordered_set<int>s`:**
You may need to define a comparison operator for the `std::vector` of `std::unordered_set<int>s` if you want to use it in a `std::set`. I think there's no predefined way to compare such complex structures, so you'll need to define your own comparison logic. Here's an example:

```
    bool operator<(const std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>& lhs, const std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>& rhs) {
        if (lhs.size() != rhs.size()) {
            return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
        }
        
        auto cmpUnorderedSets = [](const std::unordered_set<int>& a, const std::unordered_set<int>& b) {
            return std::lexicographical_compare(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
        };
        
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), cmpUnorderedSets);
    }
```

This comparison operator compares the vectors first by size and then lexicographically compares the individual unordered sets within the vectors.

With these modifications, you should be able to use `std::unordered_set<std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>>` or `std::set<std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>>` as intended in your application. These examples use Boost for hashing. If you're looking for non-Boost alternatives, you might need to implement your own hash functions or use other available hashing libraries.

Comment: This is certainly helpful. I am unsure if this is a ChatGPT answer or not :-)  In any case, I will try it out to see if it works and accept it if it does! Thanks for your time.